# "Not authorized" error when I try to open software-properties-gtk why?

Tags: linux-mint

I recently upgraded a computer From Linux Mint 20 to Mint 21 with an in-place upgrade. I recently noticed that I can no longer open the "Software Sources" dialog. Online I saw some advice to try and open `software-properties-gtk` and observe the result. When I do this, I get an error:

```
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized
```

The upgrade could be unrelated to the issue, but I did find another person with a similar issue after upgrading [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658512/how-can-i-repair-polkit). However, unlike in that question, `synaptic-pkexec` opens fine for me from the command line (and GUI), and I don't have updates to apply, my updates are clean. I have, however found that `mint-release-upgrade` gives the same error if I try to run it.

Why can't I open these programs, and how can I fix this?